# Driver not found even though it's listed in pyodbc.dataSources()

Tags: python-3.x, ms-access, odbc, driver, pyodbc

I tried to access MS Access .mdb database using pyodbc. I've set up the ODBC driver, The driver has been registered to my DSN and I can find in the `pyodbc.dataSources()`

```
​sources = pyodbc.dataSources()
dsns = list(sources.keys())
dsns.sort()
sl = []
for dsn in dsns:
    sl.append('%s [%s]' % (dsn, sources[dsn]))
print('\n'.join(sl))
```

Result in:

```
Excel Files [Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)]
MS Access DB [Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)]
MS Access Database [Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)]
dBASE Files [Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)]
```

So, I tried to access the DB by using this command:

```
con = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=H:\access-panda\data\myDB.mdb;')
```

But, I keep getting this error:

```
Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I've tried to resolved the issue.. but no luck. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The list produced by `pyodbc.dataSources()` is misleading because it shows the results from both the 32-bit and 64-bit "Platform". On a machine with 32-bit Office, running your code under 64-bit Python will produce the list

```
Excel Files [Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)]
MS Access Database [Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)]
```

but if we open the 64-bit ODBC Administrator we see that they are both for the 32-bit "Platform"

[image: odbc64.png]

and the associated drivers will *not* be available to pyodbc running under 64-bit Python.

A more reliable way to get the list of available *drivers* is to use

```python
drivers = pyodbc.drivers()
print(drivers)
```

That should only show you the drivers that are available to your particular "Platform" (i.e., 64-bit or 32-bit Python).

Comment: Yes, my python and pyodbc are 64-bit... I've updated the ODBC driver in my sysWOW64... but the issue hasn't been resolved. At the end, I downgraded both the python and pyodbc to 32-bit. Is there a way to set pyodbc-64 bit to refer  to the correct driver?

Comment: @SaberAlex - 64-bit Python/pyodbc can only work with 64-bit drivers. If 32-bit Office is installed then the Python application will have to be running as 32-bit in order to use the 32-bit Access ODBC driver.

Comment: Seems that my pyodbc-64 bits keep referring to the 32-bit driver

Comment: @SaberAlex - Do you mean that `pyodbc.drivers()` is showing the "Microsoft Access Driver ..." when you run your script under 64-bit Python?