# error SQLDriverConnect in pyodbc

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc

db_path='C:\my_path'

connection_string= "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;" %db_path

conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
```

This error occurred when run the script

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\my_path", line 25, in
>   
>       conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string) pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Driver Manager ODBC] Nome origine dati non
>   trovato e driver predefinito non specificato. (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Anyone could help me ?

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Office installed? If so, then check whether it is the 32-bit or 64-bit version and then verify that your version of Python is the same "bitness" (32-bit or 64-bit).

Comment: It doesn't work in boht cases.... both Python 3.6 64 bit and Python 2.7 32 bit returned the same error

Comment: It sounds like you simply do not have the Access Database Engine installed. You can download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Comment: I tryied this...it does not work...

Comment: Print out the following command or iterate through it: `pyodbc.dataSources()` and post for us to see if you have Access drivers/DSNs installed.

Comment: @Parfait - I find `pyodbc.drivers()` more reliable than `pyodbc.dataSources()` for troubleshooting. See related answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41602459/2144390).

Comment: this is the output of pyodbc.dataSources():                                           {'odbc_MSaccess': 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)', 'odbc_driver_access': 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)', 'dBASE Files': 'Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)', 'Excel Files': 'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)'}

Comment: pyodbc.dataSources():    conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='C:\\Users\\a200393\\Desktop\\Report_Spedito_Fatturato\\Antidumping2016.mdb';")
Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access]Errore generale.